# Sql error when using GORM's dynamic FindAllBy method - #2 is not set

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm

I have those domain classes:

```
class Person{
    String username
}

class Course {
    String code
    static hasMany = [events:Event]
}

class Event {
    Long id
    String name
    (...)

    static belongsTo = [course:Course, parallel:Parallel]
    static hasMany = [teachers: Person, students: Person,bought: Exchange, sold: Exchange]
}
```

And what I want to do is find all the events associated with a **student** and a **course**. I did this query:

```
(...)
    println "User: ${person.username}"
    println "Course: ${course.code}"


    Set<Person> persons = []
    persons.add(person)

    def events = Event.findAllByCourseAndStudents(course, persons)
}
```

But that is giving me an error `ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Parameter "#2" is not set; SQL statement:`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the second parameter in your query `Students` is the fact it's an 1:M (one to many) association and querying these associations using dynamic finders is not supported.

Take a look at [this quick overview](http://tatiyants.com/how-and-when-to-use-various-gorm-querying-options/) of the various types of querying supported by GORM/Grails to get a better understanding of what kind of options are available to you and when to use them.

As you can see using a [criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) is really what you need in this case:

```
def events = Event.createCriteria().list() {
  eq('course', course)
  students {
      eqId(person.id)
    }
  }
}
```

The above only matches against a single person, but you can modify this further to use a list of persons as you intend. I will leave that exercise to you so you can become familiar with how to create and use criteria.